# Does Windows 10 Home honor gpedit policies stored via registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, group-policy

I need to replicate a few gpedit policies on a PC with Windows 10 Home, so I applied such policies to a Windows 10 Pro PC, then tracked down the corrisponding registry entries via [Regshot](https://regshot.sourceforge.io). Now I've a nice .reg with the policies I need to apply.

So... if I import said .reg in the Windows 10 Home PC, will they be honored?

As always, I strongly appreciate an official Technet link to back every answer, but experiences are ok too as long as they are tested.

Comment: The simple answer is "yes," and many of us have tested this rather extensively.  For future reference, Microsoft actually provides us with a spreadsheet we can download called the `Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows`.  It contains a comprehensive list of settings, including both the Group Policy path as well as the corresponding registry hierarchy for each one:  [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)

Comment: You could also install `gpedit`. Instructions to install it are in my question & answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: not all settings. some only apply to Windows 10 Enterprise (like disable of lockscreen)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is *"yes,"* and many of us have tested this rather extensively.  The registry settings that were changed by the Windows 10 Pro **Local Group Policy Editor** and exported to a `.reg` file should gracefully integrate into your Windows 10 Home registry.  The only possible exceptions might be the rather rare instances where a certain specific capability exists within Windows 10 Pro that isn't available on a Windows 10 Home machines, such as various aspects of BitLocker and client Hyper-V:

[Windows 10 Editions Comparison](http://wincom.blob.core.windows.net/documents/Win10EditionsCompareTable_FINAL.pdf)

For future reference, Microsoft actually provides us with a free spreadsheet that we can download called the **Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows**. It contains a comprehensive list of settings, including both the Group Policy path as well as the corresponding registry hierarchy for each one:

[Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)